# Is it possible to prevent a git repo from using the global gitconfig file?

Tags: git, git-config

This was previously possible by setting `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL=true`. But support for that variable has been dropped.

Comment: `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL` was dropped way back in Git 1.7.5, in 2011 (via commit 8f323c00dd3c9b396b01a1aeea74f7dfd061bb7f). That's a long time! You can probably do what the Git tests do, set `HOME` to some other directory. This is not exactly the same thing since it may affect other programs.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Torek's suggestion, you can set HOME just for one git command

```
HOME=/another/path git mycommand
```

But to cancel a global config just for one repository without changing any environment variable, you would need to modify the local config of your repository to unset the configuration from the global config you don't want: local would overwrite global settings.